# В конструктуре по умолчанию какое значение присваивать полю обобщённого типа?

Tags: java

В конструктуре по умолчанию какое значение присваивать полю обобщённого типа?

```
class claz<T>
{
T information;
claz(){} //???
}
```

Comment: `null` уже не в моде?

Comment: `public claz(T arg) { 
        information = arg; 
    } `

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, а если нет аргументов в конструкторе, как изобразил автор?

Comment: @ArchDemon а если не написать, то `null` присвоится автоматом?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В конструкторе по-умолчанию не получится присвоить какое-либо конкретное значение (*параметризированного типа*) дженерику, кроме `null`.

Да и вообще, инициализировать дженерик в конструкторе по-умолчанию не нужно, он и так, без явной инициализации, будет `null` (как и любой объектный тип).